# Tab and backtick keys not working

Tags: keyboard, eeepc

I recently installed 12.10 Server Edition on my EeePC laptop and have discovered that the backtick and tab keys don't work. I haven't used this particular computer for a while so it might be a hardware problem. How can I determine if it is hardware or software?

Answer (score 1):

The standard tool to deal with key/mouse problems is `xev`. You start it from the command line, it opens a little window and until you close it every key/mouse event is recorded and displayed in that command line window.

That way you should be able to see if the keystrokes are recognized by X at all. If *yes* it is no hardware problem, if *no* it probably is.

Answer (score 0):

- Try to use the Keys while installing Ubuntu on your Laptop.
- Try to run a Live-CD (not Ubuntu i.e. Knoppix) and test the function of the keys.
- Try to use the Key in the BIOS (I don't know if the Keys have a funktion in your BIOS)

If the keys work, the Hardware is ok and you have to find a software problem.
If not, the hardware my be broken.